# Create multipart file upload from Uint8ClampedArray via fetch

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data, fetch-api, form-data, arraybuffer

I crafted a binary file in the Browser in JavaScript as `Uint8ClampedArray` and now need to upload it to a webserver as if it was chosen from a file-picker.

I tried this:

```js
var data = new Uint8ClampedArray(32);
data[0] = 0x42;
data[1] = 0x4D;
postdata = new FormData();
postdata.append('data', new Blob(data), 'test.txt');
fetch('http://localhost/',{
    method: 'POST',
    body: postdata
});
```

But it creates this request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
content-length: 230
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryfsPRCG3QGnD2bWZS

------WebKitFormBoundaryfsPRCG3QGnD2bWZS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

6677000000000000000000000000000000
------WebKitFormBoundaryfsPRCG3QGnD2bWZS--
```

And thus this Textfile :(

```
6677000000000000000000000000000000
```

How do I create a valid binary Blob()?
Thx!

Comment: what is your expected text file?

Comment: It should be "BM" and 30 NULL bytes

Comment: I know, but I want the first Byte of my file to be `42h = 66d = 'B'` and not `36h = 54d = '6' ` what it is now.

Comment: check my answer, see if it slove your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way,

```
var data = new Uint8ClampedArray(32);
data[0] = 0x42;
data[1] = 0x4D;
postdata = new FormData();

// Blob constructor takes an Array. so you need provide `[data]` not `data`
postdata.append('data', new Blob([data], {type: "text/plain"}), 'test.txt');

fetch('http://localhost/',{
    method: 'POST',
    body: postdata
});
```

Comment: Thx - but WTF? Why do I need to wrap the data-array inside an array if I want a single Blob back? I've searched over an hour for this... Thx :)

Comment: you're welcome :) 
yeah, it is really weird behavior. but make sure to add those `[]` if you use `Blobs`, `File`, or any Blob base constructors.